# Could it be a bug or performance issue in Windows 10 or laptop?

Tags: windows-10

I have the latest version of Windows 10 Home now.

But since last 1 or 1.5 years, I'm facing a weird issue. If I copy an image (could be true for text also, never paid attention) and paste it, it pastes the previously copied image. It doesn't happen always, but it *does* happen many times.

For example, if I search images on Google, right click on it and copy an image, then paste it to Photoshop, it would paste any previous image I had copied. Then if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> once again, it correctly pastes the recent image.

I'm very sure it didn't happen 1 or 2 years ago, when I had an earlier versions of Windows 10.

I'm using my laptop for 3 years with same Windows 10, but it has started happening in last 1 or 1.5 year.

So could it be a bug in Windows 10 or some performance/hardware issue?

Comment: How large is the image you are copying? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Mokubai images are less than 1 MB. The latest case occurred with a very small image. I have 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Could it be browser problem too? I think it happens when I copy image from browser. Not sure about normal copy paste in drive.

Comment: Did you maybe (accidentally) install some clipboard manager?

Comment: @DanielB no, no third party stuff related to copy and paste.

Comment: "accidentally" I'm not sure though.

Comment: Can you try this? Try going to <kbd>settings</kbd> > <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Clipboard</kbd> and uncheck the clipboard history. OR Clear your Clipboard data (Its in the same Clipboard settings)

Comment: I'll try and observe.

Comment: My thought was mainly if they were huge images that were taking time to copy to the clipboard, it could be that the program you are copying from taking its time to put stuff on the clipboard. At least some years ago Chrome [copied image ***data***](https://superuser.com/questions/757184/large-image-to-clipboard-freezes-computer/757188#757188) while Firefox copied the downloaded image *file* to the clipboard.

Comment: The image "file" is only 1MB, what is the actual image resolution?

Comment: @Mokubai my last case happened with the image in this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150486/how-is-this-glitch-effect-achieved

Comment: @Mokubai it has happened even when I have tried waiting for 2-3 seconds before pasting.

Comment: When you say "it pastes the previously copied image", does it mean that if you copy A, then B, paste getting A, then copy C, then paste, do you get B?

Comment: @harrymc I think so. Something like that. The thing is, I can't reproduce it when I need, but when I'm very busy with work, it does happen. And then I'm not in mood to experiment. Let me check again

Comment: Well, like I said, I can't reproduce it. But it sure will happen many times again.

Comment: @Mokubai & harrymc & others, I figured out a new thing. My C button on laptop keyboard is tiny bit malfunctioning. Not always but I just noticed it. It doesn't happen when I'm typing something, but looks like I can't put enough pressure on it when I press it combined with Cntrol key. When I use both keys together, I think it doesn't get enough pressure and hence actually it doesn't copy that thing. Hence the problem. I believe this is a possible problem. Because like I said it started happening in last 1 or 2 years, because laptop got old.

Comment: Hardware faults are indeed a thing. I've recently replaced a keyboard because the control key would randomly not work. Probably contacts broken. You might be able to carefully pry off the key cap and see if the membrane (little rubber thing) needs replacing or otherwise completely replace the keyboard. Many laptop keyboards can be removed and replaced. Google your model along with keywords like "keyboard cleaning" and "keyboard replacement".

Comment: @Mokubai yeah I'll probably replace, but I'm also thinking to buy a desktop. Replacement keyboards here are very expensive here and are of bad quality. And single keys are not available for sale here.